# Last object of foreign key in bulk - Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

I need find last books of authors, who are 10 years old to list:

```
[(author1.name, book32.title), (author5.name, book75.title), ...]
```

I can do:

```
books = []
authors = Author.objects.filter(age=10)
books = [(a.name, a.book_set.last().title) for a in authors]
```

but it works too long.
How can i do that entirely by ORM and database?

Comment: How many last books you want?

Comment: @doru one last (latest) book for each author

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). It will not make a second query for the related items.

```
Author.objects.filter(age=10).prefetch_related('book_set')
```

---

On a side note, use an IntegerField instead for age (if you would be storing age in years only). It will be more efficient for such queries, and you would also be able to make queries to fetch all non-adult authors:

```
child_authors = Author.objects.filter(age__lt=18)
```

Comment: It returned query set of authors:


`>>> Author.objects.filter(age=10).prefetch_related('book_set')
[<Author: Author object>, <Author: Author object>]`

Answer (score 0):

First, your `age` field should be an `IntegerField`:

```
age = models.IntegerField(max_length = 3)
```

and if you want the last, let's say, 3 books of each ten years author you can query like this:

```
 ten_years_authors = Author.ojects.filter(age=10)
 ten_years_authors_and_their_last_books = ten_year_authors.select_related('book_set')[:3]
```

Comment: Please don't pay attention to model. It's just example to illustrate what i need. Code was copied from django book with some modification. 

I need only latest book. is it reasonable to get it with [:1] or there is more fast way?

Comment: `>>> ten_years_authors = Author.objects.filter(age=10)

>>> ten_years_authors

[<Author: Author object>, <Author: Author object>]`


>>> ten_years_authors_and_their_last_books = ten_years_authors.select_related('book_set')[:3]


>>> ten_years_authors_and_their_last_books
Traceback (most recent call last):

...

FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'book_set'. Choices are: (none)`